# Quelle serait une meilleure façon d’exprimer: « Pauvre chat, il est tiraillé entre diverses positions / balancé en tout sens?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, lexique, formulation

> Pauvre chat, il est entraîné dans toutes les directions.
>
> Pauvre chat, il est entraîné en tous sens.
>
> Pauvre chat, il est tiraillé entre diverses positions.
>
> Pauvre chat, il est tiraillé en tout sens.
>
> Pauvre chat, il est balancé en tout sens.
>
> Pauvre chat. Il est balancé dans toutes les directions.

Il est question d’un chat qui, malgré lui, tient lieu de jouet: des enfants (deux) le prennent, l’un l’entraîne dans une direction, l’autre l’entraîne dans une autre direction et ainsi de suite.
Merci.

Comment: Tirailler would work but is not used with 'en': "Pauvre chat, il tiraillé dans tous les sens"

Comment: "Il **est** tiraillé", pour être précis.

Comment: @Reyedy Yes, thanks for spotting this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certaines de vos propositions fonctionnent bien à mes yeux, notamment le verbe "balancer".

Je propose :

> Pauvre chat, il est **secoué** dans tous les sens.

From the [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/secouer/71738) definition:

> Imprimer de brusques mouvements à quelque chose, à quelqu'un [...]

Je trouve qu'on retrouve donc bien l'idée des mouvements "sans ménagement" que subit le pauvre animal entre les mains d'enfants peu précautionneux.

D'autres verbes pourraient fonctionner : balader, traîner (un peu comme un sac), balloter (proposé par @jlliagre)...

Comment: Aussi: *balloter*.

Comment: Merci, balloter est une bonne proposition ! Je l'ai ajoutée à ma réponse :)

Answer (score 1):

Inspiré d'une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/44210/25619), au Québec je dirais :

> Pauvre chat, il se fait [brasser](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/brasser).

Un peu de même sens que *secouer*, mais signifiant aussi [*malmener*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/malmener), ce dernier verbe pouvant aussi faire l'affaire. Je préfère la construction réflexive à valeur passive avec le verbe [*faire*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/faire/2). La référence au sens, positions et directions est inutile ici à mon avis. Par ailleurs il peut être utile pour les parents de rappeller à leur enfant qu'un animal n'est pas un jouet mais bien un être sensible (QC : [intro.](https://www.mapaq.gouv.qc.ca/fr/Productions/santeanimale/securitebea/Pages/situationjuridiqueanimal.aspx), [CCQ](https://www.canlii.org/fr/qc/legis/lois/rlrq-c-ccq-1991/derniere/rlrq-c-ccq-1991.html#LIVRE_QUATRIEME_DES_BIENS_1228528) ; FR : [intro.](https://www.vie-publique.fr/eclairage/18774-bien-etre-animal-une-preoccupation-croissante), [CC](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/section_lc/LEGITEXT000006070721/LEGISCTA000006090204/#LEGISCTA000006090204)), ce qui doit induire un comportement adapté.

Comment: Dans les cas graves, on pourrait utiliser le mot *maltraiter* avec la question « que fait l'entourage ? ».